# Why does nesting my divs break document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue while designing a music player. My music player works with the following code:

```js
playlist_index = 0;

// Set object references
playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
volumeslider = document.getElementById("volumeslider");
curtimetext = document.getElementById("curtimetext");
durtimetext = document.getElementById("durtimetext");
playlist_status = document.getElementById("playlist_status");
playerImg = document.getElementById("playerImg");

// Audio Object
audio = new Audio();
audio.src = dir+playlist[0].song_url;
audio.loop = false;
playlist_status.innerHTML = playlist[playlist_index].song_name + '-' + playlist[playlist_index].band_name;

// Add Event Handling
playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
seekslider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){ seeking=true; seek(event); });
seekslider.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){ seek(event); });
seekslider.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){ seeking=false; });
volumeslider.addEventListener("mousemove", setvolume);
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){ seektimeupdate(); });
audio.addEventListener("ended", function(){ switchTrack(); });
audio.addEventListener("play", function(){ playbtn.style.background = "url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/pause.png) no-repeat"; });

// Functions
function switchTrack(){
    if(playlist_index == (playlist.length - 1)){
        playlist_index = 0;
    } else {
        playlist_index++;   
    }
    playlist_status.innerHTML = playlist[playlist_index].song_name + '-' + playlist[playlist_index].band_name;
    audio.src = dir+playlist[playlist_index].song_url;

    setTimeout(audio.play(), 2000);     
}
```

(plus some more functions for updating seek bars and times) and the following HTML:

```html
<div id="audio_player">
    <div id="playerImg"></div>
    <div id="audio_controls">
        <button id="playpausebtn"></button>
        <p id="playlist_status"></p>
        <div id="sliderHolder">
            <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
            <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
            <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
        </div>
        <button id="mutebtn"></button>
        <br/>
        <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I start housing elements in container divs, the above code fails to update the time and the seek slider doesn't work. The housed and styled audio player HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="audio_player">
    <img src="wp-content/uploads/band-photos/Logo.png" id="playerImg">
    <p id="playlist_status"></p>
    <div id="audio_controls">
        <div id="sliderHolder">
            <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
            <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
            <span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
        </div>
        <div id="musicButtons">
            <button id="playpausebtn"></button> 
            <div id="volumeHolder">
                <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/virtue-child/speaker.png" id="volButton">
                <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there an issue when I begin to house elements in divs and searching the DOM for them? Again, the JavaScript works with the first set of HTML, not the second.

Comment: You should trim this down to the minimum amount of javascript and html that can reproduce the problem.  In all likelihood you have a typo and will probably solve the error while you attempt to reproduce it.

Comment: `setTimeout(audio.play(), 2000);` is surely not what you wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the input. It looks like in styling the new player I removed the mute button. Therefore: 'mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);' was throwing an error and causing the rest of the functions not to work.